# How to change count of kendo ui grid at run time

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I am trying to set total count value of Grid manually on button click event. When button click event is catched by javascript, then I pass value that will be search . At last, I would like to change total count of grid.Problem is, I am able to get count but i don't know how to set new count to grid Datasource/Schema as total value. I am trying to change grid dataSource data and total at run time on grid search where grid having server paging option set to true.

```
function searchgridChange(value)
                {
                    $("a").attr("href", "#");
                    grid = $("#searchstoregrid").data("kendoGrid");
                    var size = grid.dataSource.pageSize();
                    var skip = grid.dataSource.skip();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('plugin'=>'inventory','controller'=>'Outwords/wholeData')); ?>",
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType:'json',
                        data:{id:value, size:size, skip:skip},
                        success: function(data){
                            if(data['data']){
                                var record = data['data'];
                                var total = data['total'];


                                $('#searchstoregrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(record);
                                $('#searchstoregrid').data('kendoGrid').schema.total(total);

                            }
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, exception){
                            alert(jqXHR.status);
                        }
                    });
}
```